# Sharing images on social media

Tags: swift, swift5

In the app I'm building, I want to share images on social media. Instead of using Apple's `UIActivityViewController` (which shows all the options at once), I would like these separate buttons to share an image to the social media the buttons represent.

What is the best way to do this?

[image: UI Design screenshot showing social media buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should stick to `UIActivityViewController` to avoid eventual app rejection during the App Store publication Review process.
You could create a method for every button you have created that opens the `UIActivityViewController` only for the intended social network,
to do that you have to exclude all `ActivityType` except the one related to your button's social network:

```
@IBAction shareOnFacebook(_ sender: UIButton) 
{
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Your message"], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        // Here: exclude all ActivityType except postToFacebook ...
    ]    

    present(activityViewController, animated: true)
}
```

For a complete list of available `ActivityType` see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/activitytype)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using `UIStackView`.